# Некорректная кодировка ответа с запроса

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть одна версия приложения (asp net 3) на 2 разных веб серверах.
1. system localization: russian, win-server 2019
2. system localization: eng, win-server 2008
Также есть actionfilter, который в определенных случаях возвращает 400-ую ошибку

```
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

С первого сервера ответ приходит с некорректной кодировкой
[image: Ответ первого сервера]
Со второго корректный
[image: Ответ второго сервера]
На обоях приложениях web.config одинаковый, содержит следующее

```
<globalization culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru-Ru" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Нужно какое либо решение помимо смены локализации сервера и поднятия версий библиотек. Фильтр должен возвращать 400-ую ошибку, а не какую то другую
Пробовал:
1. Создание кастомной страницы с ошибкой - не реализуемо именно для 400 ошибки
2. другой метод возврата 400-ой ошибки - нашел только аналогии на  core

Comment: 1. Переведите вопрос. 2. Проверьте кодировку самой странички `HTML`. 3. У меня иногда так "глючело" не понятно из-за чего => делал так: открывал `*.cshtml` в `notepad++` и менял кодировку.

Comment: 1. так хоть больше шанс, что ответят, надежды уже почти нет) п2. все тот же utf-8. по п.3 - это не отдельная кастомная страничка, по логике я просто возвращаю код ошибки, и должно выйти стандартное окно ошибки - но в итоге получаю эту.

Comment: Я очень много промучался именно на `linux` т к везде стоял `utf-8`, но иероглифы не исчезали...мне помог п.3...я понимаю что это не отдельная страничка...я просто говорю в чем может быть проблема...может это покажет вам решение.

Comment: Это в дебаг режиме у вас?

Comment: нет, все сборки в релизе

Comment: решил: <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors> - добавил веб конфиг, чтобы страница ошибки не формировалась на сервере, а на клиент просто улетал http-код, и уже браузер выдавал окно ошибки